# Refresh fragment when dialogfragment is dismissed

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any way I can detect when a DialogFragment is dismissed, so that i can update its parent fragment?

Answer (score 37):

You can add a listener and override the onDismiss of your fragment dialog :

```
public class DismissDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener;

    public void setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener) {
        this.onDismissListener = onDismissListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (onDismissListener != null) {
            onDismissListener.onDismiss(dialog);
        }
   }
}
```

Then, on the parent, you set a listener :

```
DismissDialog d = new DismissDialog();
d.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
d.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sometag");
```

Comment: This is a bad solution, as your listener will not survive recreation, and your callbacks will 'magically' stop working. This is explained in detail here: https://medium.com/@lukeneedham/listeners-in-dialogfragments-be636bd7f480

See here for a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64479938/6007104

Comment: I agree with @Luke, this is a very old answer (5 years now) and we have better tools and solutions for this problem now.

Answer (score 3):

Override [onDismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) of DialogFragment, or when building the underlying dialog, set a listener with [setOnDimissListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29).

Comment: This informs the `DialogFragment` that it has been dismissed, but not it's parent fragment which is what the question asked.

Comment: The parent can use these methods to get a callback and respond when it is dismissed. See this answer for usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29518363/445348

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Gazer answer, it doesn't work for me, I am using different fragment class

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

But I got this working

1. Create an interface class

   ```
   public interface MyDialogListener {
       void OnCloseDialog(Object obj); //you can put any object here
   }
   ```
2. Implement the interface class in the Parent Fragment

   ```
   public class ActionBarFragment extends Fragment implements MyDialogListener{

       @Override
       public void OnCloseDialog(Object obj) {
           //Do you refresh
       }
   ```
3. and then I add the listener inside the DialogFragment

   ```
   public class SpecialDialogFragment extends DialogFragment { 

       MyDialogListener mListener;

       public SpecialDialogFragment(MyDialogListener listener) {
           this.mListener = listener;
       }

       @Override
       public void onStop() {
           super.onStop();
           if(mListener!=null)
              mListener.OnCloseDialog(null);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this is to embed your DialogFragment within an Activity and display the activity as a Dialog, there's a tip in the following link that explains how:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

You can use this to update the underlying Fragment because when the Dialog (which is an Activity) is finished, onResume() will be called on the underlying fragment. Add code to update the state of the fragment in the onResume() method and that's all there is too it.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, but what about API 8+? This was added in API 11

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this in my project. What I have is an activity with a ListFragment. In that list fragment, when a particular item is clicked, I display a DatePickerFragment (a custom DialogFragment that displays a DatePickerDialog). When a date is selected, I want the ListFragment to be refreshed.

To achieve this, in the activity that hosts the ListFragment (and it also hosts the DatePickerFragment, as a matter of fact) I implemented a method that simply replaces the ListFragment with a new instance, like so:

```
public void criteriaChanged()
{
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new FilterFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

I call this method from the DatePickerFragment, from onDateSet():

```
FilterActivity fa = (FilterActivity) getActivity();
fa.criteriaChanged();
```

This does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The top rated answers here have issues.

You cannot hold listeners as instance variables in a `DialogFragment`, as they will not survive recreation, and you will left wondering why your callbacks 'magically' stop working.

You can read more about this here:

https://medium.com/@lukeneedham/listeners-in-dialogfragments-be636bd7f480

This article offers a couple of real solutions, of which my favourite is to use `targetFragment` with a custom interface. For intercepting the dismiss, that looks like:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main), DummyDialogCallback {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        openDialogButton.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = DummyDialog()
            dialog.setTargetFragment(this, DIALOG_DUMMY)
            dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DummyDialog")
        }
    }

    override fun onDummyDialogClick() {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Dummy click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    companion object {
        const val DIALOG_DUMMY = 1
    }
}

class DummyDialog : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_dummy, container, false)

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog)
        val callback = targetFragment as? DummyDialogCallback
        callback?.onDummyDialogClick()
    }
}

interface DummyDialogCallback {
    fun onDummyDialogClick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Luke mentioned, the top answer has issues. You can also achieve what you want with `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` without any custom interfaces or listeners.

**1- Create a inner FragmentLifecycleCallbacks () class:**

```kotlin
    // Create a FragmentLifecycleCallbacks (inner) class:
    inner class ChildFragmentCallbacks : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
         override fun onFragmentPaused(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
            super.onFragmentPaused(fm, f)
            if(f is YourDialogFragment){
                // YourDialogFragment is closed, you can update parent fragment here
                updateParentFragment()
            }
        }
    }
```

**2- Register it on onCreate():**

```
childFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(ChildFragmentCallbacks(), false)
```

total code:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager

class YourParentFragment : Fragment() {

    // ...

    // Create a FragmentLifecycleCallbacks (inner) class:
    inner class ChildFragmentCallbacks : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
         override fun onFragmentPaused(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
            super.onFragmentPaused(fm, f)
            if(f is YourDialogFragment){
                // YourDialogFragment is closed, you can update parent fragment here
                updateParentFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateParentFragment(){
      // Do it  
    }

    // Register it on onCreate():
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        childFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(ChildFragmentCallbacks(), false)
    }

    // ...

}
```