# refresh fragment when dialogFragment dismiss

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

in my application, my Fragment AppointmentFrag contains a customListView which load data from database
on itemClickListener of listView, i open a DialogFrament

This is my itemClick method

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    RowItem listRow = (RowItem)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String date=dateString;
    String time=listRow.gettime();
    arguments.putString("date", date);
    arguments.putString("time", time);
    SherlockDialogFragment fragment = (SherlockDialogFragment)  Fragment.instantiate(appContext, SdleCrte.class.getName(),arguments);
    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "create");
}
```

my DialogFragment is `SdleCrte.class`

i need to do some operations on the dialogFragment ie, i add a new item to my table in the database. and when i click on the positive button the dialog will dismiss and need to show the new item in the listView which contains in the AppointmentFrag
i override the onResume in my AppointmentFrag and write code for recollecting data from the database but my onResume function written in the AppointmentFrag doesnt call

how we can refresh my listView when the Dialog closed. or how we can identify my dialogFrag dismissed and run some part of code.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late to answer, but in your `DialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface frag) {
    super.onDismiss(frag);
    // DO Something
}
```

Here you can call a method in your `Activity` using `(MyActivityClassName)getActivity().myMethod();`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123149/3922705

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

But I got this working

1. Create an interface class

   ```
   public interface MyDialogListener {
       void OnCloseDialog(Object obj); //you can put any object here
   }
   ```
2. Implement the interface class in the Parent Fragment

   ```
   public class ActionBarFragment extends Fragment implements MyDialogListener{

       @Override
       public void OnCloseDialog(Object obj) {
           //Do you refresh
       }
   ```
3. and then I add the listener inside the DialogFragment

   ```
   public class SpecialDialogFragment extends DialogFragment { 

       MyDialogListener mListener;

       public SpecialDialogFragment(MyDialogListener listener) {
           this.mListener = listener;
       }

       @Override
       public void onStop() {
           super.onStop();
           if(mListener!=null)
              mListener.OnCloseDialog(null);
       }
   ```